# How to disable submit button until the password fields are matching in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function PassCheck() {

    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var vpassword = document.getElementById('vpassword');

    if(password.value!= vpassword.value){
        document.getElementById("button1").disabled = true;  
    }
        }  

</script>
```

HTML code:

```
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required onchange='PassCheck();'/> <br>
    Verify Password: <input type="password" name="vpassword" required id="vpassword" onchange='PassCheck();'/> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1" name="submit" onchange='PassCheck();'/>
```

The submit button is disabled only the first time and the disbale button doesn't work after second attempt. I am not sure why its not working. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add an `else` condition that re-enables your button once the values match:

```js
function PassCheck() {
  var password = document.getElementById('password');
  var vpassword = document.getElementById('vpassword');

  if (password.value != vpassword.value) {
    document.getElementById("button1").disabled = true;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("button1").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required onchange='PassCheck();' /> <br>
Verify Password: <input type="password" name="vpassword" required id="vpassword" onchange='PassCheck();' /> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1" name="submit" onchange='PassCheck();' />
```

Answer (score 1):

`onchange` occurs only when the element loses focus, so try to use `onkeyup` or `oninput` events. Also don't forget to set `disabled` to `false`.

```js
function PassCheck() {
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var vpassword = document.getElementById('vpassword');

    document.getElementById("button1").disabled = password.value.length === 0 || 
                                                  password.value != vpassword.value;
}

PassCheck();
```

```html
Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required onkeyup='PassCheck();'/> <br>
Verify Password: <input type="password" name="vpassword" required id="vpassword" onkeyup='PassCheck();'/> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1" name="submit"/>
```

Comment: I agree that the OP should use `onkeyup`. This solution is better.